# How to accumulate query condition in active record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

Fast example,

```
@user = User.all
@user = @user.where(live: true) if params[:live]
@user = @user.where(another: true) if params[:another]
@user = @user.where(another2: true) if params[:another2]
@user = @user.where(another3: true) if params[:another3]
.
.
.
```

this code is hitting the db a lot, if has lots of params

So I'm thinking of saving the search condition to a var and execute it at final like this.

```
where_condition += '.where(live: true)' if params[:live]
where_condition += @user.where(another: true) if params[:another]
where_condition += @user.where(another2: true) if params[:another2]
where_condition += @user.where(another3: true) if params[:another3]
    .
    .
    .

@user = User.all.where_condition
```

Is there any good solution like this?

Comment: In the first example, I don't think it's will hitting db a lot. Because rails know when to hit the db.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails uses lazy-evaluation of ActiveRecord relations, therefore your code doesn't hit the database multiple times but only once, when the query is evaluated.

You can easily check it by looking at your logs. You will notice the query is executed only once.

Therefore, your code is fine. Still, there are a couple of improvements you can adopt. The first one is to use the `!` method to chain the conditions.

Rather than

```
@user = User.all
@user = @user.where(live: true) if params[:live]
@user = @user.where(another: true) if params[:another]
...
```

you can use

```
@user = User.all
@user.where!(live: true) if params[:live]
@user.where!(another: true) if params[:another]
```

The second one, is that you should definitely avoid to build chain of conditions directly in the controller, because it makes your code very hard to be tested. In order to test the successful execution of the query, you will have to build an entire controller test.

Refactor the code out in a model method.

```
class User
  def self.search(params)
    scope = all
    scope.where!(live: true) if params[:live]
    # ...
    scope
  end
end
```

In your controller

```
@users = User.search(params)
```

This will make unit testing of your model and controller easier as you can test them independently. The code is also more maintainable on the long period.

Answer (score 0):

#### Actually, *no*. Your code works better than you think.

It doesn't hit the database a lot, it only does one query. To clarify, I'm talking about this:

```
@user = User.all
@user = @user.where(live: true) if params[:live]
@user = @user.where(another: true) if params[:another]
@user = @user.where(another2: true) if params[:another2]
@user = @user.where(another3: true) if params[:another3]
.
.
.
```

You may have got that feeling when running the given code through the Rails console. The catch is that behavior in your application is slightly different. When evaluating the given code line-by-line you'll get intermediate values of `@user` (since that's what an assignment returns) that the console will try `inspect` it for you to examine and as such, will execute each query.

**Your application's code won't do that since it doesn't run in an interactive session.**

ActiveRecord relations are **lazy**: as such, they don't execute unless you request data from them, through `inspect`, `each` or any other method that requires actual data. `where` doesn't.

You could use a bit of refactoring here, since a boatload of `if`s is in no way DRY, but it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try-

```
@user = User.all
@user = @user.select {|u| (params[:live] ? u.live : true) && (params[:another] ? u.another : true) && (params[:another2] ? u.another2 : true)}
```